# Ubuntu black screen on boot

Tags: boot, 18.04

I was trying to solve some issue with virtualbox following a tutorial. Maybe I've done `apt remove linux-header` or something like that and then I've reinstalled virtualbox, suddenly it required to install GRUB, and so I did it in all my partitions.

After that, everytime I reboot my PC it gets stuck in the famous black screen. However, if I keep pressing Right Shift, and then "Advanced Options" and then select any option, the ubuntu starts all right.

I don't want to do it everytime I need to boot my PC, so how can I make it start automatically again?